# PHP MVC with CRUD

Tags: php, mysql, crud

I wrote a simple MVC from scratch on PHP, why is it my getting this message `Resource id #7` when i tried to print_r the data i receive?

Here's my code:

Controller:

```
$data = $this->query->db_select();
print_r($data);
include 'view/show_all.php';
```

Model/query.php

```
 public function db_select(){
    $test = $this->query_db->select("SELECT * FROM sis");
    return $test;
}
```

Model/connect.php

```
<?php
/**
* DB Connect PDO
*/
class Connect
{
    private $DBCOnnect;
    public function __construct(){
        $this->DBConnect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
        mysql_select_db("activity");
    }
    public function insert($query) {
        return mysql_query($query);
    }
    public function delete($query) {
        return mysql_query($query);
    }
    public function select($query) {
        return mysql_query($query);
    }
    public function update($query) {
        return mysql_query($query);
    }
    public function close() {
        mysql_close($this->DBConnect);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: -1: a *DB Connect PDO* which does not use `PDO`? Also `mysql_*` function are deprecated since PHP 5.5

Answer (score 0):

The return value from `mysql_query()` is a resource. You can't just `print_r()` it. You have to fetch rows from the resource in a loop.

You shouldn't be using the deprecated mysql extension anyway. Use PDO.

Comment: how can i implement PDO?

Answer (score 0):

[mysql_query](http://us.php.net/mysql_query) only returns a query resource, not the fetched data.

You will have to add a call to [mysql_fetch_array](http://us.php.net/mysql_fetch_array) or similar to get what you want.

```
$data = $this->query->db_select();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($data) {
    print_r($row);
}
include 'view/show_all.php';
```

Comment: how can i use it? sorry, still new to this.